# Confused on what row operation relates these two matrices?

Tags: linear-algebra

My homework presents me with the following problem. I'm not asking to be given the answer because I obviously want to learn the subject, but I just don't understand how to get this answer:

Identify the elementary row operation that has been used to transform

\begin{bmatrix}-1&2&1&1\\1&1&-1&2\\2&0&1&-1\end{bmatrix}

into the row-equivalent matrix

\begin{bmatrix}-1&2&1&1\\1&1&-1&2\\0&-2&3&-5\end{bmatrix}

The only logical way I can think of to get a 0 in the third row, first column would be to multiply R1 by 2 and add it to R3. But this would result in a third row of 
0 4 3 1 
rather than 
0 -2 3 -5

Can someone hint me as to what row operation is used here?

Answer (score 3):

It's the second row multiplied by $-2$, and then added to the third row.

Comment: Oh duh. I think you meant row though. But thanks

Answer (score 0):

To find second matrix,you need to do some changes in first matris.
You need to multiply second row of first matrix by $-2$ and add in third row.